# Not getting object in componentDidMount while trying to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm calling my api inside componentDidMount and I want to set state to use the values later on, but I'm getting nulls. The API itself works, tested with postman, also calling other methods also works inside the componentDidMount.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = window.location.pathname;
        let id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        console.log(id)
        userService.getDepartment(id).then(departments => this.setState({ ...departments }));
        console.log(this.state.address);
    }
```

This is what I see in the console log.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNF4l.png

My get function:

```
function getDepartment(id) {
    const requestOptions = { method: 'GET', headers: authHeader() };
    return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/api/department/${id}`, requestOptions);
}
```

Comment: Could you `console.log(dapartments)` inside the `.then()` and edit your post to show us what the console logs?

Comment: When I did it like this:
userService.getDepartment(id).then(departments => console.log(departments));
it gives me null

Answer (score 0):

The state won't update until AFTER the did mount. Can you try seeing if the result shows up inside a `render()`?

Edit: Didn't notice there wasn't a `.catch()` could you try adding that in and see what the console logs?

something like this:

```
//... rest of the component
componentDidMount() {
    let url = window.location.pathname;
    let id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    console.log(id)
    userService.getDepartment(id)
      .then(departments => this.setState({ ...departments }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(this.state.address);
}
//... rest of the component
```

Comment: Tried it, still says null

Comment: @QuelindKajiura Hmm, is it possible to see what the `userService` code looks like?

Comment: I edited my original post with the get method.

Comment: Thanks :). I made an edit to my post as well. Could try adding the `.catch(err => console.log(err));` and see what happens?

Comment: No error was caught (nothing changed in the console log)

Comment: @QuelindKajiura Sorry, I'm stumped. I feel like the API route should be throwing a `sorry, couldn't fullfill your request` error, or a `404` or something. It seems like the API route thinks it's successfully fullfilling the request, but the "successful request" is a null value. I would try playing around with Postman and see what happens when you send a "bad request" (something you know is not going to work) to that route... but yea, time for debugging :(